# Blue bird return promise missing warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, bluebird

I use the following code and I got the warning

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from
>   it

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var glob = Promise.promisify(require('glob'));

glob("files/*.js")
            .then(function (files) {
               files.forEach(function (file) {
                    ...
                     invoke(data,response,fn,entity,req);
                });
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ', err);
            }
        )
```

what should I do to avoid it?

I read the documentation of BB and it seems that I should `return` the promise

my question is where? I guess that inside the invoke function but not sure how

This is the inovke function

```
var invoke = function (data,res,fn,entity,req) {
....
    for (var data in entity.app[0]) {

         var name = entity.app[0].function;
                try {
                    fn[name](req, res);
                }
                catch (err) {
                    res.status(500).send("Error" + err);
                }
                if (!res.headerSent) {
                    res.end("done", 200);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

in addition I've tried to return the promise like following which doesnt work

```
var invoke = function (data,res,fn,entity,req) {
....
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    for (var data in entity.app[0]) {

         var name = entity.app[0].function;
                try {
                    resolve(fn[name](req, res));
                }
                catch (err) {
                    res.status(500).send("Error" + err);
                }
                if (!res.headerSent) {
                    res.end("done", 200);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

I dont want to suppress the warning I want to understand how to solve it...

If I need to add some additional info please let me know, Im stuck here:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test the following code but you should have an approach like this:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var glob = Promise.promisify(require('glob'));

glob("files/*.js").then(function (files) {

    return Promise.all(files.map(function (file) {
            return invoke(data,response,fn,entity,req);
        })
    );
}).catch(function (err) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
    res.status(500).send("Error" + err);
}).finally(function(){
    if (!res.headerSent) {
        res.end("done", 200);
    }
});

var invoke = function (data,res,fn,entity,req) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        for (var data in entity.app[0]) {

             var name = entity.app[0].function;
             try {
                 fn[name](req, res);
             }
             catch (err) {
                reject(err);
             }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! this solve the issue which was complicated to understand (at least for me) can you please why this solve the issue and not just return...

Comment: You needed to return the new promise to the chain, and as you were creating multiple promises, need to use Promise.all(). When you catch the error on invoke function, just have to reject that specific promise in order to propagate the error onto the chain.